# Publishing a single file via org-publish

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

How do you save a publishing behavior so that only a single org file out of a directory of org files is published?

`org-publish-file` could be used with a larger unused project definition, but content could be published unintentionally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was non-obvious and the scenario of single/select files wasn't mentioned in any documentation specifically, so here's my solution: **(only the last two lines are relevant)**

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      `(("project"
         :base-directory "~/org/"
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :publishing-directory "~/html_pub/"
         :exclude ".*"
         :include ["project.org"])))
```

(specify the parent directory, exclude all files, and explicitly include the file(s) which you intend to publish)